# Silverlight WCF Service Client Instantiation

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm encountering a problem when creating the WCF service client object.

HelloServiceClient helloWorldClient = new HelloServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IDataAccess");

Here's the content of my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataAccess" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWcf/Service1/mex" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDataAccess" contract="IHelloService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataAccess" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The error message is as following

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with
>   name 'BasicHttpBinding_IDataAccess' and contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IHelloService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this name could be found in the client element.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress address)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName)    at
>   SilverlightApplication1.ServiceReference1.HelloServiceClient..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName)    at
>   SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.Button_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)

Could someone help me on this problem? and please do let me know if you want any other codes/config.

Comment: Is it not as simpel as your contract name needs to be 'ServiceReference1.IHelloService'  that would tie in with my file. VS will auto generate them for you

Comment: Please then mark the answer below correct - it helps with your rep and makes the site work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found above - the contract name needs to be 'ServiceReference1.IHelloService' as indicated in the error.